# Why Google Cloud Build is passing data between steps without any configuration in cloudbuild.yaml file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, google-cloud-build

Refer to Google Cloud documentation [Passing data between build steps](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/pass-data-between-steps)

It says -

> Cloud Build runs your tasks as a series of build steps, which execute
> in isolated and containerized environments. **After each step, the
> container is discarded.** This allows you to have totally different
> tools and environments for each step, and by default, any data created
> in one step can't contaminate the next step. But sometimes you may
> need to persist state from one step of a build to use in subsequent
> steps.

Now refer to the below cloudbuild.yaml code from [Google Cloud Documentation example.](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/building/build-nodejs#configuring_nodejs_builds)

```
 
steps:
# Step 1
- name: node
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['install']

# Step 2
- name: node
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['test']
```

Question: Why and how the above example runs successfully even if we don’t have a step to
install the requirements again in step 2. Because as per my thinking, the step 2 should get fail (but it is not actually) as the installations done in step 1 **should get discarded** as per the documentation.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason both steps succeed is because the command `npm install` will download/install the dependencies of your application in a persistent volume in CloudBuild runners which is shared between all of your steps and then the `npm test` will run against your app code which is sitting under the same shared volume. This volume name is `/workspace`.

Take a closer look at this part of the documentation which will give you more details on how the data is shared between steps: https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/pass-data-between-steps#passing_data_using_workspaces

Comment: Hi @Ngg, please consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you find it helpful. Thanks

Comment: @CaioT, if /workspace functionality is already there by default, then I guess it contradicts with the documentation statement: "After each step, the container is discarded. And any data created in one step can't contaminate the next step."?

Comment: @Ngg, the container is discarded indeed but the volume /workspace is mounted by default on every container (each step) to work as persistent data in your builds.

Comment: @CaioT, now I got it. I was taking container and it's workspace to be the same thing.